# SQL CE "Объект был открыт" 80040E05

Tags: sql, delphi

Microsoft SQL Compact Edition. Delphi XE3 SP2 edition.

SQL CE таблица имеет колонку `varchar` размером более 127 символов.

При попытке создать запрос к таблице

```
select * from ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ
```

с колонкой `varchar` размером более 127 символов выдается ошибка

> SQL CE "Объект был открыт" 80040E05

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Можно попробовать  изменить `CursorLocation` у коннекта и квери на `clUseServer`